# time and date in Python Language

Tags: python, date, time

I have log file

```
Thu Mar 22 21:14:36 2012; TCP;
Thu Mar 22 21:15:15 2012; TCP;
Thu Mar 22 21:16:23 2012; TCP;
Thu Mar 22 21:17:51 2012; TCP;
Thu Mar 22 21:18:45 2012; TCP;
```

I need to get logs for the last three minutes, the script must be in Python
I tried to use datetime and slice function.

```
import datetime
x=datetime.datetime.now()
print x #result 2012-03-22 21:19:09.918804
```

But when I cut the date and leave only the time, the system generated an error

```
a=x[11:20]
```

...TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is unsubscriptable...
I know that the algorithm should work well: the current time, take three minutes, but i don't have any ideas...but rather a lack of knowledge

Comment: Please clarify your question. The `TypeError` is normal: `x` is not a string, it's a datetime object. Where is your three minute interval? Hint: you should expect to find `datetime.timedelta` in your code if you are dealing with intervals. Where are you reading the log file and comparing the time?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `datetime.datetime.now()` python returns a datetime object, not a string. That's why you can't take a slice from it directly. When you call `print x`, python internally calls `str(x)` to format it in the way you're seeing. So, you need `a = str(x)[11:20]`.

However, a better solution is to use [datetime.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.strftime).

As a segue from datetime.strftime, if you want to then get a datetime object from the your preexisting log file (in order to check check if the time has been in the last 3 minutes), you can use [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.strptime) like so: `datetime.strptime(line.split(';',1)[0],"%a %b %H:%M:%S %Y)`.

Comment: I believe that the real question is actually "how do I extract the log lines from the last 3 minutes".

Answer (score 2):

`datetime.datetime` objects don't support slicing. What I think you're trying to do is `str(x)[11:20]`: that is, convert `x` to a string (which is what `print x` shows) and take the 11:20th indices of that.

Better might be to use [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior): `x.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`.

But: once you have that string, you'll need to do some kind of comparison, and I'm not entirely sure how you're doing that. You might need to go in the other direction:

```
import datetime
import sys

cutoff = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)
line_format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y; TCP;"

lines = iter(sys.stdin) # or iter(f) for a file object f

# skip all the lines before three minutes ago
for line in lines:
    logtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(line.strip(), line_format)
    if logtime >= cutoff:
        print line
        break

# print out the rest of the lines
for line in lines:
    print line
```

This could be made much fancier, but I think that'll do it. You might need to do some more string processing if the [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) format isn't exactly right, or the lines have actual content other than `"TCP;"`.